# Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max) or varchar(max)

Tags: t-sql

```
select 
    EmailAttachmentFilename,
    IsNull(EmailAttachmentFilename,'').Replace('*','%') as EmailAttachmentFilename2
    from dbo.MyTable1
```

gives the following error:

> Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max).

I also added the Convert function, but that didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when you have been doing C# or Python for a long time, then switch back to SQL. Replace is not a method in T-SQL, it is a function.

Here is the correct use of the Replace function.

```
select 
    EmailAttachmentFilename,
    Replace(IsNull(EmailAttachmentFilename,''),'*','%') as EmailAttachmentFilename3
                         from dbo.Ch_BizTalk_IncomingEmail_Routing
from dbo.MyTable1
```

When I did this, I got a much more clear error:

```
select 
    EmailAttachmentFilename,
    EmailAttachmentFilename.Replace('*','%') as EmailAttachmentFilename4
 from dbo.MyTable1
```

Resulting error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'Replace'.
```

However, when using the IsNull function, the error is rather obfuscated.